# Mod_rewrite rule if no other rules match

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way to do a sort of "catch all" rule that will only be matched if no other rules have been matched in my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this rule as last rule to catch any request that could not be mapped onto an existing file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ catch-all.foo
```

Answer (score 0):

if you put your rule at the bottom, and have your other rules with a [L], it'll be considered the catch-all.